How to convert DTO property types to CLR types in Dapper
I'm using Dapper and Dapper.Contrib in a project. I want to asbtract the type used for keys in my Dto so that I can change it easily in the future.
The code below throws a System.NotSupportedException saying "The member 'X' of type 'Y' cannot be used as a parameter value"
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=equus;integrated security=true;Encrypt=false"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        connection.Execute(@"If not exists (select name from sysobjects where name = 'User')
            CREATE TABLE dbo.[User](UserId int identity(1,1) primary key clustered, Name varchar(200))");
        var user = new User() { Name ="OSO", UserId = 1 };
        connection.Insert(user);
        connection.Close();
    }
}

public struct Key
{
    private readonly int _value;
    public Key(int value) { _value = value; }
    public static implicit operator Key(int value) { return new Key(value); }
    public static implicit operator int(Key key) { return key._value; }
}

public class User
{
    public Key UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }=string.Empty;
}

I am aware that I can do it casting manually, for example:
connection.Execute("INSERT INTO dbo.[User] (UserId, Name) values(@UserId, @Name)", 
    new {UserId=user.UserId, user.Name});

but I'd like to use Dapper.Contrib methods like Insert<T> or Update<T>
I know I can use SqlMapper.SetTypeMap to do some level of manipulation, like column name mapping, but I can't find a way to tell Dapper "whenever you find a property of type T convert it to CLR type C using this delegate".  Any suggestions?

I found a [partial] solution myself. The trick is using a TypeHandler
I found documentation here: https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-type-handling-4b447b97c620
So I implemented this:
using Dapper;
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

public class KeyTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Key>
{
    public override Key Parse(object value)
    {
        return new Key((int)value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, Key value)
    {
        parameter.Value = (int)value;
    }
}

Then, in my startup, I added:
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new KeyTypeHandler());

Unfortunatelly this does not work when you have auto-generated primary keys, like in my case. UserId is INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
